# How to get date in YYYY-MM-DD format from rest client?

Tags: java, postgresql, rest, date, postman

I have a table that contains a created_date column of type 'date'.

When I execute this query

```
select created_date as "Date" myTable
```

Output is:

```
2018-02-23 05:34:12 //Not desired output
```

So, When I execute this query

```
select (created_date::TIMESTAMP::DATE) AS "Date" from myTable
```

Output is:

```
2018-02-23 // Desired Output
```

But the problem arises when I try to execute this query from a rest client(postman) through a rest api. Now the output on response console is in Unix Timestamp.

```
1519344000000
```

But I want it in the same format YYYY-MM-DD in response as well.

Comment: try `select (created_date::TIMESTAMP::DATE::text) AS "Date" from myTable`

Comment: Do you want to insert a date from Postman into the database or are you trying to get the correct format to show in the response data?

Comment: @Danny trying to get the correct format to show in the response data

Comment: @VaoTsun thanks! its working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your rest converts date to unix timestamp, you can try casting date to text to avoid conversion, eg:

```
select (created_date::TIMESTAMP::DATE::text) AS "Date" from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out one more solution in case we need the date to be in a specific format say "DD/MM/YYYY"

```
select to_char((created_date::TIMESTAMP::DATE),'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "Date" from myTable
```